# Vlookup type mismatch

Tags: vba, vlookup, variant, mismatch

I'm trying perform a vlookup in VBA and the code doesn't seem to be getting cells value properly. The variables rowrng and colrng are being returned as #N/A

```
  Sub DosiDo()

'Declare Variables
Dim colnum As Long
Dim rownum As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim rowrng As Variant
Dim colrng As Variant

'Set worksheets
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim newWs As Worksheet
Dim table1 As Range
Dim ws1 As String

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set newWs = wb.Worksheets.Add
newWs.Name = "DosiDo"

    
    With Workbooks("210721-LeaveRecords.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")
            Set table1 = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(7, 9))
    End With

    wsl = "AS Darwin"

    rowrng = Application.VLookup(ws1, table1, 7, False)
    colrng = Application.VLookup(ws1, table1, 8, False)
    
    newWs.Cells(i + 1, 4).Value = rowrng
    newWs.Cells(i + 1, 5).Value = colrng

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dim `ws1` wrong.

Change `ws1` to `wsl`

```
  Sub DosiDo()

'Declare Variables
Dim colnum As Long
Dim rownum As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim rowrng As Variant
Dim colrng As Variant

'Set worksheets
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim newWs As Worksheet
Dim table1 As Range
Dim wsl As String

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set newWs = wb.Worksheets.Add
newWs.Name = "DosiDo"

    
    With Workbooks("210721-LeaveRecords.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")
            Set table1 = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(7, 9))
    End With

    wsl = "AS Darwin"

    rowrng = Application.VLookup(ws1, table1, 7, False)
    colrng = Application.VLookup(ws1, table1, 8, False)
    
    newWs.Cells(i + 1, 4).Value = rowrng
    newWs.Cells(i + 1, 5).Value = colrng

End Sub
```

Comment: `Option Explicit` will save you from this type of error.

Comment: @TimWilliams: How?

Comment: @Capt.Krusty Just type `Option Explicit` on the top

Comment: @TimWilliams: Okay, so the `Option Explicit` is the function that automatically changes the "typos" in varaibles?

Comment: @Capt.Krusty - no it doesn't "fix" this type of issue: it just stops you makin typos in your variables which do not match the declared name (obv. will not help you if they end up match some *other* declared name...)

Answer (score 0):

N/A results when VLOOKUP cannot find the key value in the first column of the range provided when the last parameter is "FALSE". Maybe that's the issue??

Table1 address is $B$2:$I$7. Your VLOOKUP functions are looking for values from $H$2:$H$7 and $I$2:$I$7, respectively, for the row in $B$2:$B$7 that has "AS Darwin". Is that what you're after?

If so, maybe you could try using AutoFilter?

```
With table1
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ws1, Operator:=xlAnd
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(2).Resize(1, 2).Offset(, 5).Copy NewWS.Cells(i + 1, 4)
    .AutoFilter 'turns autofilter off
End With
```

The `.Areas(2)` is needed if table1 is NOT formatted as an Excel Table (VBA "ListObject"), and if the matching row is NOT the first row after the headers (row 3). Also, `.Resize(1, 2)` returns only two columns of the first row of matches, and starts at the column 6 columns from the left of the table (`.Offset(, 0)` = Column B in this case).

You'll need to trap for the case where there are no visible rows after the filter (e.g., `If .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count > 1 or .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas.Count > 1 Then ...`)